# How to decompile a exe in to a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, exe, decompiler

I have turned my batch file in to a exe but not I can not decompile it, if anyone has any ideas  let me know. A list of Decompiler programs Would also be acceptable.

Comment: I used a program called "bat to exe converter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think all .exe files can be converted into a .bat file. Unless you know for sure your .exe file was made from a .bat file then that would be possible. What does your file do? Try to find a way to edit the .exe file. It might have the .bat coding in it.

Comment: but it is encrypted with a password so it might cause a problem. i dont know

Answer (score 0):

Run the .exe and reclaim it from the temp folder, but you have to be quick or kill mid process because the wrapper code will delete the script on exit.

[Forum Reference](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/exe-to-bat/23719.html)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. i used a program anyway.

Comment: This would be easier if your original Batch code have a `pause` or `set /P` commands. When the Batch code is running from the .exe file it exist in readable text form in a disk file, so you just need to locate it.

Comment: But i didn't put a  Pause or set /p so what should i do?

Comment: @Antp: What I've done before in a similar situation is this:  Use a process monitor to find out where the .exe wrapper writes the batch file.  Then remove delete permissions for your user on that directory.  Then run the program again and it'll create the batch file but not be able to delete it.  The key point is that your batch-to-exe program almost certainly writes a copy of your batch file somewhere on your file system, runs it, and then deletes it.